# Azure Media Services Broadcast to Another Service

Tags: azure, youtube, live-streaming, twitch, azure-media-services

I have looked through the examples for creating a live stream on Azure, but this leaves you with a url where the stream can be viewed at. I'm wondering if there's anyway to push the live stream to another service (such as twitch.tv or youtube live streaming)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently live streaming doesn't support to push to another service.